# Plot XLabel date format from object 'dateIndex'

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

My object list 'dateIndex' looks like this...

```
2013-10-16 12:42:49
2013-10-16 12:42:49
2013-10-16 12:42:49
2013-10-16 12:42:49
2013-10-17 09:09:53
2013-10-17 09:10:40
2013-10-17 09:10:42
2013-10-17 09:20:02
2013-10-17 09:30:02
2013-10-17 09:40:02
2013-10-17 09:48:52
2013-10-17 09:59:01
```

I need get these date and time on the x label but I don't know how.

My plotting function:

```
def graphData(dateIndex,irValue):

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((5,4), (0,0), rowspan=4, colspan=4)#, axisbg='#07000d')
    ax1 = plt.subplot(1,1,1)

    date = mdates.strpdate2num('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
    converters = { dateIndex:mdates.strpdate2num('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S') }
    #this is where i get an error -> unhashable type: 'list'
    ax1.plot(date,irValue)
    ax1.grid(True)
    ax1.spines['bottom'].set_color("#5998ff")
    ax1.tick_params(axis='y')
    ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.MaxNLocator(10))
    ax1.axis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were creating a `mdates.strpdate2num` function but never applying it to your actual date strings.

A fixed `graphData` function is given below where a list comprehension has been used to apply the function. I've also fixed two other problems with your function, namely: you should use `plot_date` rather than `plot` and you you missed the `x` from `xaxis` when setting your formatter.

```
def graphData(dateIndex,irValue):

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((5,4), (0,0), rowspan=4, colspan=4)#, axisbg='#07000d')
    ax1 = plt.subplot(1,1,1)

    date = mdates.strpdate2num('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

    datenum = [date(i) for i in dateIndex] # Apply your date function here.

    ax1.plot_date(datenum, irValue)
    ax1.grid(True)
    ax1.spines['bottom'].set_color("#5998ff")
    ax1.tick_params(axis='y')
    ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.MaxNLocator(10))
    ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S'))

    fig.autofmt_xdate()

    plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi '@Ffisegydd', 
Thank you so much, code worked after a long struggle, you are diamond to resolve the error. 
How do I plot separate xaxis with datenum and irValue using ax1.plot(irValue),
since after the moving average is done with irValue data size shrinks so I get an 
error: 'ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, Is there any way to plot those 
two components separate, please give your thoughts, Thanks in advance

Comment: def graphData(dateIndex,irValue):

    Av1 = movingaverage(irValue,50)

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((5,4), (0,0), rowspan=4, colspan=4)
    ax1 = plt.subplot(1,1,1)

    date = mdates.strpdate2num('%Y-%m-%d')

    datenum = [date(i) for i in dateIndex] # Apply your date function here.

    ax1.plot(Av1)
    ax1.grid(True)
    ax1.spines['bottom'].set_color("#5998ff")
    ax1.tick_params(axis='y')
    ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.MaxNLocator(10))
    ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d-%m-%Y'))

    fig.autofmt_xdate()

    plt.show()

Comment: Hi ramas. If you have a new question about working with moving averages you should ask a new question on Stack Overflow. That way the questions are kept neat and separated. Good luck!